# Microsoft SQL Database Error

Tags: sql-server

One of software is connected to the Microsoft SQL server. That database was working fine but now cannot log in it and cannot start that server also. When I start it manually it automatically disables.

When I tied to log using SQL Server Manegment Studio it says following error.

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to 192.168.50.173\KONSYS.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

The system cannot find the file specified

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Operating system: Windows 10
Microsoft SQL Server version: 2016
That .mdf file size is 1.13 GB

How can I solve this problem? All password and username are correct.

Error Log:

```
2018-08-27 16:43:40.02 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) 
    Apr 29 2016 23:23:58 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 17134: )

2018-08-27 16:43:40.02 Server      UTC adjustment: 5:30
2018-08-27 16:43:40.02 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2018-08-27 16:43:40.02 Server      All rights reserved.
2018-08-27 16:43:40.02 Server      Server process ID is 5712.
2018-08-27 16:43:40.02 Server      System Manufacturer: 'Hewlett-Packard', System Model: 'HP ProDesk 600 G1 TWR'.
2018-08-27 16:43:40.02 Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.
2018-08-27 16:43:40.02 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.KONSYS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2018-08-27 16:43:40.02 Server      The service account is 'AS\SMNB-CHAWPADHI$'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:40.02 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.KONSYS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.KONSYS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.KONSYS\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2018-08-27 16:43:40.02 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -s "KONSYS"
2018-08-27 16:43:40.08 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 4 cores per socket and 4 logical processors per socket, 4 total logical processors; using 4 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:40.08 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:40.09 Server      Detected 3986 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:40.09 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2018-08-27 16:43:40.33 Server      Default collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033)
2018-08-27 16:43:40.64 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary. 
2018-08-27 16:43:41.00 Server      InitializeExternalUserGroupSid failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.
2018-08-27 16:43:41.00 Server      Implied authentication manager initialization failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.
2018-08-27 16:43:41.53 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2018-08-27 16:43:41.55 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 3724 at 8/27/2018 1:52:36 PM (local) 8/27/2018 8:22:36 AM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:41.59 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0 Active CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:41.63 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:41.65 Server      Database Instant File Initialization: enabled. For security and performance considerations see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL Server Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:41.81 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1, 
2018-08-27 16:43:41.84 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
2018-08-27 16:43:41.84 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
2018-08-27 16:43:41.97 spid4s      [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [1] 'master'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:42.44 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\.
2018-08-27 16:43:42.49 spid4s      Starting up database 'master'.
2018-08-27 16:43:42.83 spid4s      [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [1] 'master'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:42.99 spid4s      [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [1] 'master'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:43.15 spid4s      108 transactions rolled forward in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:43.24 spid4s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:44.03 spid4s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:44.12 spid4s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:44.59 spid4s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2018-08-27 16:43:44.61 spid4s      Server name is 'SMNB-CHAWPADHI\KONSYS'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:44.83 spid13s     The certificate [Cert Hash(sha1) "BDCDB039F589A706BCCA5C0E1115286602632D39"] was successfully loaded for encryption.
2018-08-27 16:43:44.83 spid13s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 49775].
2018-08-27 16:43:44.83 spid13s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 49775].
2018-08-27 16:43:44.83 spid13s     Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\KONSYS ].
2018-08-27 16:43:44.84 spid13s     Server named pipe provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\MSSQL$KONSYS\sql\query ].
2018-08-27 16:43:44.84 spid13s     Dedicated administrator connection support was not started because it is disabled on this edition of SQL Server. If you want to use a dedicated administrator connection, restart SQL Server using the trace flag 7806. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:44.84 spid13s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:44.84 Server      SQL Server is attempting to register a Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Kerberos authentication will not be possible until a SPN is registered for the SQL Server service. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:44.86 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/SMNB-Chawpadhi:KONSYS ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 63. Failure to register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies and if the SPN has not been manually registered.
2018-08-27 16:43:44.86 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/SMNB-Chawpadhi:49775 ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 63. Failure to register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies and if the SPN has not been manually registered.
2018-08-27 16:43:45.40 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2018-08-27 16:43:45.40 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'AVREPORTER'. [CLIENT: ::1]
2018-08-27 16:43:45.40 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2018-08-27 16:43:45.40 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'AVREPORTER'. [CLIENT: ::1]
2018-08-27 16:43:45.62 spid14s     A new instance of the full-text filter daemon host process has been successfully started.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.08 spid17s     [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [4] 'msdb'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.08 spid18s     [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [5] 'AVREPORTER'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.08 spid19s     [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [6] 'aspnetdb'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.08 spid18s     Starting up database 'AVREPORTER'.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.08 spid17s     Starting up database 'msdb'.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.08 spid19s     Starting up database 'aspnetdb'.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.09 spid6s      [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [32767] 'mssqlsystemresource'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.09 spid6s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.12 spid19s     [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [6] 'aspnetdb'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.17 spid17s     [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [4] 'msdb'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.19 spid6s      The resource database build version is 13.00.1601. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.19 spid6s      [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [32767] 'mssqlsystemresource'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.23 spid6s      [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [32767] 'mssqlsystemresource'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.24 spid17s     [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [4] 'msdb'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.25 spid17s     1 transactions rolled forward in database 'msdb' (4:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.27 spid18s     [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [5] 'AVREPORTER'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.32 spid19s     [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [6] 'aspnetdb'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.35 spid17s     0 transactions rolled back in database 'msdb' (4:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.47 spid19s     2559 transactions rolled forward in database 'aspnetdb' (6:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.47 spid18s     [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [5] 'AVREPORTER'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.49 spid19s     0 transactions rolled back in database 'aspnetdb' (6:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:46.87 spid18s     187 transactions rolled forward in database 'AVREPORTER' (5:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:47.04 spid18s     0 transactions rolled back in database 'AVREPORTER' (5:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-08-27 16:43:47.15 spid6s      [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [3] 'model'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:47.15 spid6s      Starting up database 'model'.
2018-08-27 16:43:47.20 spid6s      [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [3] 'model'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:47.24 spid6s      [INFO] HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [3] 'model'. XTP Engine version is 0.0.
2018-08-27 16:43:47.25 spid6s      Error: 9003, Severity: 20, State: 1.
2018-08-27 16:43:47.25 spid6s      The log scan number (33:388:1) passed to log scan in database 'model' is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise, restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during startup.
2018-08-27 16:43:47.25 spid6s      SQL Server shutdown has been initiated
2018-08-27 16:43:47.25 spid6s      SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

Comment: If the service isn't up and running you won't be able to log in. Read the SQL Server's error log, it might give you a clue about why it can't get up.

Comment: How can I read it?

Comment: You can read the error log file using any text editor (e.g. notepad). The exact location may vary depending on your installation but should be like "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\errorlog".

Comment: I updated my question with error log

Comment: Tempted to close this as "tip of the iceberg." Typically the easiest and fastest solution to a corrupt install is to just install a fresh, new instance and move your user databases there.

Answer (score 3):

**Reason**

> Error: 9003, Severity: 20, State: 1.
>   2018-08-27 16:43:47.25 spid6s      The log scan number (33:388:1) passed to log scan in database 'model' is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise, restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during startup.
>   2018-08-27 16:43:47.25 spid6s      SQL Server shutdown has been initiated

The model database log file seems to have corruption which SQL Server detected. This is not allowing model database to come online which in turn will not allow Tempdb re-creation. Since tempdb is not able to come online the SQL Server is terminating.

**Solution**

You would have to restore model database. Please refer to [The SQL Server Instance That Will not Start](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/backup-and-recovery/the-sql-server-instance-that-will-not-start/). Its a combined list by MVP Gail Shaw. Please look at the section corrupt and missing model database files.